# How to write a function to create a button and print out the value with vanilla javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, function, button, input, printing

```
function Rate() {
    var input = document.getElementById('idea').value;
    
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = input;
}

<input id="idea">
 
<button id="btn">Rate it!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Problem: It doesn't print out my input.
Can anyone help?

I want to print out my value on the screen.

Comment: How/when are you calling `Rate` function?

Comment: added document.getElementById('btn');
console.log(comment);

Comment: Added document.getElementById('btn');
console.log(comment);

Comment: See what are [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) and [how to add an eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to an element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `onclick` function of the button

```js
var comment = []
function Rate() {
    var input = document.getElementById('idea').value;
    
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = input;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = Rate;
```

```html
<input id="idea">
 
<button id="btn">Rate it!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```